# C++ divide for loop with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<thread>
    using namespace std ;
    void dowork(size_t s , size_t e, size_t *se )
    {
     for(size_t  i = s ; i < e; i++)
            se += i ;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int numthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() ;
        size_t start = 0 ;
        size_t end = 12;
        size_t chunk = (end - start + (numthreads - 1))/numthreads ;
        cout<< chunk ;
        std::thread t[numthreads] ;
        size_t sum = 0 ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numthreads ; i++ )
        {
            size_t s = start + i * chunk ;
            size_t e = s + chunk ;
            t[i] = std::thread(dowork, s, e, &sum) ;


        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numthreads ; i++)
            t[i].join() ;

        cout<<sum ;



    }
```

I keep getting floating point exception. I have tried datatype Auto, size_t, double, float. The goal is to show thread for loop. simple program add 0 to 12   and divide the work among the core.

Comment: where do you get an exception? compile with debug symbols and run in a debugger.

Comment: The code shown doesn't even have floating point operations, there's no way to tell what's really happening that has an issue.

Comment: The expression `se += i` will not do what you expect it to.

Comment: @VoidStar What about this line `(end - start + (numthreads - 1))/numthreads`

Comment: @crush No floating point operations there, it's all integer operations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's right. Doh!

Comment: You should consider using dynamic allocations since it depends on `numThreads` variable. Declaring threads as an array won't even compile; Try `std::thread* threads = new std::thread[numthreads];`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
size_t chunk = (end - start + (numthreads - 1))/numthreads ;
```

t0:

```
size_t chunk = (numthreads>0 ? (end - start + (numthreads - 1))/numthreads) : end - start)
```

Comment: Why? What does this accomplish and how will it benefit the OP? Usually a good idea to actually tell the OP what's wrong and what to do to fix it rather than just dumping code as an answer.

Comment: Per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency num_threads can be 0!  In this case, i suspect the thing you want to do is default to 1 thread.

Comment: Comments are not the place to expand on your answer. Please edit your post and include additional information there.